# fatal: division by zero attempted

Tags: awk

when ever I am trying to calculate mean and standard deviation using awk i am getting "awk: fatal: division by zero attempted" error.

my command is

```
BEGIN{
recvs = 0;
routing_packets = 0;
}
{
state       =   $1;
layer       =   $3;
tipe_data   =   $6;
}
{
if (state == "r" && tipe_data == "tcp" && layer=="AGT") recvs++;
if (state == "s"  && layer == "AGT" && tipe_data =="AODV") routing_packets++;   
}

END{
printf("##################################################################################\n");

printf("\n");

printf("                       Normalized Routing Load = %.3f\n", routing_packets/recvs);

printf("\n");

printf("##################################################################################\n");
}
```

thanks

Comment: One `tipe data` should probably be `tipe_data`. But that has nothing to do with division by zero, I suppose...

Comment: Try printing `state`, `layer` and `tipe_data`, make sure they contain what you expect... Print also `routing_packets` and `recvs` before you divide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, values assigned to recvs and routing_packets variables is zero.

```
recvs = 0;
routing_packets = 0;
```

And you are trying to to divide it. That is,

```
routing_packets/recvs
```

Which results in,

```
awk: fatal: division by zero attempted" error
```

Answer (score 0):

If this if check never succeeds the value of recvs will be equal to 0

```
if (state == "r" && tipe_data == "tcp" && layer=="AGT") recvs++;
```

Your program will go on nevertheless and hit this line  **routing_packets/recvs** 
You should handle the scenario where recvs is equal to 0 depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
printf("                       Normalized Routing Load = %.3f\n", routing_packets/recvs);
```

to

```
if (recvs)printf("                       Normalized Routing Load = %.3f\n", routing_packets/recvs);
```